# Altair - action button missing in bar chart

Tags: python, altair

New to Altair (wonderful package!)

In 2 similar charts, one has an action button but the other does not.  Any insights into this? I would like to have the action button (to save to SVG) in both.

The following code:

```
chart = alt.Chart(df1).mark_bar(size = 25).encode(
    x = alt.X('drg3:N',sort=None, 
              axis = alt.Axis(title = "DRG")),
    y = alt.Y('discharges:Q', 
              axis = alt.Axis(title = "Discharges", format = "s"),
              scale = alt.Scale()),
).properties(
    title = "Top DRGs, based on Discharges in 2017",
)
chart
```

produces a chart with action button

[image]

However, the following code

```
chart = alt.Chart(df1).mark_bar(size = 25).encode(
    x = alt.X('drg3:N',sort=None, 
              axis = alt.Axis(title = "DRG")),
    y = alt.Y('disc_times_pay:Q', 
              axis = alt.Axis(title = "Payments (in '000,000,000s')", format = "s"),
              scale = alt.Scale()),
).properties(
    title = "Top DRGs, based on Payments in 2017",
)
chart
```

produces a similar graph, but the action button is missing

[image]

Comment: How are you rendering the charts? All that Altair does is to produce a JSON description of a chart, which is then ingested by some rendering frontend (e.g. JupyterLab, Jupyter Notebook, altair_viewer, etc.). The actions menu is displayed by the renderer, so that is the relevant piece of information here.

Comment: @jakevdp Jupyter notebook, Anaconda, Mac OS Catalina

Comment: In the notebook, are you rendering charts with the default renderer, or via the vega nbextension (``alt.renderers.enable('notebook')``)?

Comment: using default renderer

Comment: Can you provide a [miminal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue? (your code does not define ``df1``)

Comment: my apologies ```raw_data = {'DRG' :[871, 470, 291, 190, 189, 872],\
 'Discharges' : [597736, 510632, 359442, 215525, 165613, 157851] }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['DRG', 'Discharges'])
df1
```

Comment: I ran the code but my chart looks nothing like yours. Please edit your question to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208158/discussion-between-mvigoda-and-jakevdp).

Comment: my apologies, again. I tried to reproduce the issue again and did not have the problem with the action button. One thing that I forgot to mention is that the style of formatting used in the Title and Axes was imported using %run from another ipynb. Sorry that I wasted your time on this.